# how to access variables in vuejs data() from js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, jquery-select2

I am using vuejs3 and select2, but vue js is not working with select2 library. For this problem I use input with hidden type. code:

```
<select class="form-select" data-control="select2" id="trainingevents" data-placeholder="choose ...">
  <option></option>
  <option v-for="event in events" :value="event.id">{{ event.event_title }}</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="hiddenInputEvent">
```

I write js code in **mounted()** in vue js for when select changed I get value of option and add it to input with type hidden. code:

```
$('#trainingevents').on('change',function(){
  var optionsValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  var getInputValue = document.getElementById('hiddenInputEvent').value;
  var tmp = document.getElementById('hiddenInputEvent').value = getInputValue + ',' + optionsValue;
});
```

and my vuejs code is:

```
export default{
    name: 'TrainingeventRegister',
    data(){
        return {
            users: '',
            events: '',
            selectedEvent: '',
            selectedEvents: [],
            totalSalary: 0,
        }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    mounted(){
        axios
        .get('/load/users')
        .then(response => (this.users = response.data));
        axios
        .get('/load/events')
        .then(response => (this.events = response.data));

        $('#trainingevents').on('change',function(){
            var optionsValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
            var getInputValue = document.getElementById('hiddenInputEvent').value;
            var tmp = document.getElementById('hiddenInputEvent').value = getInputValue + ',' + optionsValue;
        });

    }
}
```

now my question is how to access selectedEvent variable in **data()** from change jquery event like this:

```
    mounted(){
        axios
        .get('/load/users')
        .then(response => (this.users = response.data));
        axios
        .get('/load/events')
        .then(response => (this.events = response.data));

        $('#trainingevents').on('change',function(){
            var optionsValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
            var getInputValue = document.getElementById('hiddenInputEvent').value;
            var tmp = document.getElementById('hiddenInputEvent').value = getInputValue + ',' + optionsValue;
           this.selectedEvent = tmp // when I use this line i get undefine this.selectedEvent
        });

    }
```

When I use `this.selectedEvent = tmp` it returns this.selectedEvent is undefined.
Any idea what is wrong with this code?
Thanks.

Comment: You should using this [wrapper component](https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2/tree/npm-publish-code-for-vue3)

Comment: You preferably shouldn't. Don't use direct DOM access with Vue without a good reason, this includes the use of JQ. You'll end up with odd problems that are hard to solve because the framework wasn't intended to be used like that.